# how to replace last value to kWh in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

hi I have a code in pandas (I wanna convert Watt to kWh here):

```
new = df['datetime;W'].str.split('(;| )',n=2, expand=True)
df['Date_Time']= new[0]
df['Watts']= new[2]
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], format='%Y%m%d:%H%M', errors='ignore')
df['Watts'] = df['Watts'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
kiloWatt = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object','datetime']) * 0.001
df['kWatt'] = kiloWatt['Watts']
df['kWh']= 'NaN'
df.drop(columns =['datetime;W', 'Watts'], inplace = True)
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if index < len(df)-1:
       df.loc[index,'kWh'] = ((df['kWatt'][index] + df['kWatt'][index+1]) / 2)  *((df['Date_Time'][index+1]-df['Date_Time'][index]).seconds / 3600)
       df['kWh'] = df['kWh'].astype(float)
df.drop(columns =['kWatt'], inplace = True)'''

    date_time        kWh
2016-12-31 21:55:00  0.0
2016-12-31 22:55:00  0.0
2016-12-31 23:55:00  NaN
```

I would like to be able to get value in my last row also but I don't know how!!!???
And I would like too if it is possible, improve my code (get col:date_time in 30min not 1h) if you have idea. Thanks

Comment: `df.iloc[-1]` gives you the last row.

Comment: Can you also provide the input/ initial dataframe prior to your code.